# Regex For Decimal Avoid Or Syntax

Tags: .net, regex

I need to validate the following (in .Net).

A number, with or without a decimal point, minimum 1, maximum 6 characters total (decimal included).
If there is a decimal, there can only be one decimal place.
So these are ok:
123
123456
1234.5
123.4
etc..

These are not:
1234567
123.15
1.100
etc.

I know how to match a variable number of digits, but is the only way to accomplish the above by using the or syntax (by using a | I think?) Can you achieve something like this without the or syntax?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid or ?

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid the "or" easily by using even more obscure constructs, like look-around assertions. Why do you want to avoid it?

E.g. this should do what you ask:

```
^(?=.{1,6}$)\d+(\.\d)?$
```

Comment: +1, nice trick using lookbehind to ensure a fixed length for the match

Answer (score 1):

The regex for this would be `^(\d{1,6}|\d{1,4}\.\d)$`. Here's how to derive it:

```
\d                        A single digit
\d{1,6}                   1 to 6 digits [a]
\d{1,4}\.\d               1 to 4 digits, followed by a dot and one digit [b]
(\d{1,6}|\d{1,4}\.\d)     Either [a] or [b] anywhere within the input
^(\d{1,6}|\d{1,4}\.\d)$   As above, but the input must contain nothing else
```

For excellent regular expression reference, go to http://www.regular-expressions.info.

Comment: No. If you test `123.4` it would find `123` and `4`. See mine.

Comment: @Aliostad: Forgot to put the regex at the top around `^$` -- thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(\d{1,5}\.\d|\d{1,6})\b
```

Have a look [here](http://rubular.com/r/0ngf8TzIaI) for **demo**.

Comment: This would fetch the 123456 from 123456.789, which may be undesirable.